# ¿Java tiene constructor por defecto?

Tags: java, poo, constructor

En un libro llamado "Java a fondo" se especificaba que al crear una clase en Java esta formaba un constructor por defecto. Pero, en una pregunta de la App SoloLearn de Android aparecía que los constructores por defecto en Java no existen. ¿Cuál de los 2 tiene la razón?

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Las clases en Java siempre tienen constructor por defecto. En Android, puede ser que haga referencia las clases anónimas puntuales, normalmente usadas para eventos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno de hecho he leido que al no crear un constructor dentro de tu codigo , el compilador lo hara teniendo una estructura de `Constructor(){}` lo cual es un constructor por defecto te invito a que leas mas en el siguiente link:

http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.co/2012/07/normal-0-21-false-false-false_103.html

Answer (score 0):

La maquina virtual de Java, genera el constructor sin parámetros por defecto para poder instanciarlo. Pero pues es una buena practica generar al menos un constructor con parámetros porque en muchas ocasiones no tiene sentido crear un objeto vació.